# keycloak realmresourceprovider corse

Tags: cross-domain, keycloak

I'm evaluating some IAM Products and encountered a Problem with CORS with the RealmResourceProvider from Keycloak. 
The goal is to write an angular4 client able to create user and manage groups with a REST interface from Keycloak.

**Server-side:**

I tried to implement the Rest interface with the RealmResourceProvider Interface in order to access Realm and User Data as easy as possible. 
I followed the Beercloak example (github.com/dteleguin/beercloak) and got it working, but without a custom theme (only the REST-Resources). My own application is packaged as Jar.
I managed to call this Facade via REST Client and it worked (By calling localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token first and then stuffing the Token in the Authorization-Header).

**keycloak-configuration**
But if i test it via Browser, I will need to enable Cross-Origin-Ressource-Sharing. In order to do that I added the 'enable-cors' attribute to the 'keycloak.json' in the server application:

```
{
"realm": "master",
"auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
"ssl-required": "external",
"resource": "pharmacyRessource",
"public-client": true,
"enable-cors": true
}
```

Additionally I Created a Client in the Keycloak Admin.
[Client Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZPzv.png)

**Client-Side and Problem:**

The angular client uses Mohuks ng2-keycloak service from github.com/mohuk/ng2-keycloak/blob/master/src/keycloak.service.ts to obtain the accesstoken. - Works fine. 
But in case i make a GET-request to my Resource, the preflight fails because of missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header:
[Error 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv9E8.png)
The keycloak.json used for initializing the keycloak-client in javascript looks like this:

```
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "pharmacyRessource",
  "public-client": true
}
```

**My failed solutions:**

- I tried to implement a CORS Filter, but i didn't succeed because i
  couldn't get it registered by keycloak.
- I also implemented the @OPTIONS Method and appended CORSE Headers by
  myself. Didn't work either, because the Method never got invoked.
- I tried to package it as .war in order to enabling a custom
  Filter/Provider, but failed at registering the Resources to keycloak.

My testing environment is the offical docker container from hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: I managed to get OPTIONS Method invoked. But i have to add the Corse header to all Methods by myself.  I will now attach the headers by myself according to the WebOrigins of the Requested ClientModel.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need enable CORS in your keycloak server (that runs in wildlfy)  . You can do it, putting the code bellow into your standalone.xml from wildfly:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                 <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
        <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"/>
        <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
        <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"/>
        <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age"/>
                <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
            <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="http://localhost"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="1"/>
      </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak should automatically handle CORS headers for you when you set `"enable-cors": true` in the client configuration JSON file as you mention.

The reason why the server is not adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is because Keycloak rejects the origin unless the token is configured (via the admin console) to do so.  It's very subtle, but it's mentioned in the docs (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.1/securing_apps/index.html):

> enable-cors
>   This enables CORS support. It will handle CORS preflight requests. **It will also look into the access token to determine valid origins.**

Notice the last sentence.  The "valid origins" in the "access token" are part of the client configuration, which is set via the admin UI.

Comment: RealmResourceProvider is no bound to any client so you can noot set it up via keycloak console